# MVC Razor recursive list numbering

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a recursive list like this:

```
@ShowTree(pages, 1)

@helper ShowTree(List<pages> pages, int level)
{

    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count(); i++)
        {

            <li>
                <h1>@pages[i].PageName</h1>

                @if (pages[i].children.Any())
                {
                    @ShowTree(pages[i].children, level + 1)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

This works all fine, but I need the list to have a format of:

1

1.1

1.2

1.2.1

1.2.2

1.3

And so on.

The reason that I have the "level"-parameter is an earlier attempt to create this, without luck.

**Also, I need each heading to be leveled, with `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` (...).**

All help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If there is any way to solve this with css, that would also be a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this :

```
@ShowTree(pages)

@helper ShowTree(List<pages> pages, int level=1, string prefix ="")
{
    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count(); i++)
        {

            <li>
                @Html.Raw(String.Format("<h{0}>", level)) @String.Format("{0}{1}", prefix, i + 1) @pages[i].PageName @Html.Raw(String.Format("</h{0}>", level))

                @if (pages[i].children.Any())
                {
                    @ShowTree(pages[i].children, level + 1, String.Format("{0}{1}.", prefix, i + 1))
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Except from the head-tags being displayed as pure text, everything else seems to work.

Comment: @Annish Yes, Html.Raw were missing. I guess you figured it out by now. Edited my answer anyway. Thx for the follow-up